# read from a html file and edit those lines python

Tags: python, readlines

i have this text file

**test.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td id="A">A</td>
      <td id="B">B</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td id="C">C</td>
    <td id="D">D</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</html>
</body>
```

**python file**

```
f = open('test.html')
ans = "A"
line = f.readline()
    print(line)
    if ans == 'line':
      #change the row A to a dash: <td>-</td>
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

so what i want to do is to scan through the html file and when i find the column A i can change it into a dash and save the file
i am a beginner in python and don't know much about handling file input and output 
Please Note: Without Libraries

Comment: how does look your desired output ?

Answer (score 3):

Using Python **without** any libraries you can use the following code to replace a line that contains A with what you want, I just replaced the line with builtin function [replace()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/) with a string:

```
<td id="A">-</td>\n
```

Code:

```
ans = "A"
lines = []

#open file
with open(r'test.html', mode='r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines(): # iterate thru the lines
        if ans in line: # check if is in ans in line
            line = ans.replace(ans, '<td id="A">-</td>\n') # replace the line containing the and with the new line, you can change to what you want. 
        lines.append(line)

#write to a new file
with open(r'myfile.html', mode='w') as new_f:
    new_f.writelines(lines)
```

`myfile.html` content:

```
 <html>
     <body>
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <td id="A">-</td>
                 <td id="B">B</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td id="C">C</td>
                 <td id="D">D</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Open test.html for reading
with open('test.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file.read(), features='html.parser')

    # Go through each 'A' tag and replace text with '-'
    for tag in soup.find_all(id='A'):
        tag.string.replace_with('-')

    # Store prettified version of modified html
    new_text = soup.prettify()

# Write new contents to test.html
with open('test.html', mode='w') as new_html_file:
    new_html_file.write(new_text)
```

Which gives the following *test.html*:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td id="A">
     -
    </td>
    <td id="B">
     B
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="C">
     C
    </td>
    <td id="D">
     D
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah but i really wanna do it without libraries

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, BeautifulSoup is for sure a very nice option, but given that you are a beginner, I would like to suggest to you this regex approach.

```
import re
fh= open('test.html')
content = fh.read()
content = content.replace(re.findall("<td id=\"A\">A</td>",content)[0],"<td id=\"A\">--</td>")
fh.close()
fh=open('test.html','w')
fh.write(content)
```

Or if you want a more efficient code in terms of space and you know file handling in python well, then you can look at this approach as well:

```
import re
fh = open("test.html",'r+')
while True:
    currpos= fh.tell()
    line = fh.readline()
    if re.findall("<td id=\"A\">A</td>",line):
         line = line.replace(re.findall("<td id=\"A\">A</td>",line)[0],"<td id=\"A\">--</td>")
         fh.seek(currpos)
         fh.writelines(line)
    if line == '':
        break
fh.close()
```

Comment: this is a good solution just one query what if i want this line to have varibles example :
` var_1 = 'A'  `

`content = content.replace(re.findall("<td id=\"var_1 \">var_1 </td>",content)[0],"<td id=\"var_1 \">var_1 </td>")`
how will i go about doing that

Comment: You can use string concatenation :
`content = content.replace(re.findall("<td id=\""+var_1+"\">"+var_1+" </td>",content)[0],"<td id=\""+var_1+" \">"+var_1 +"</td>")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use beautifulsoup or HTMLParser libs. beautifulsoup is a lot easier to use, though. You can read how to use it here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/python-beautifulsoup-basic